# Possible to get GPS exif data from Camera photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, uiimagepickercontroller, exif

I have an app that launches the camera:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And I implement the delegate to get the image taken by the camera:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
...
}
```

Inside that delegate I would like to save the image with the GPS exif data if possible.

The info object after taking the picture has the following keys:

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata
```

The metadata key seems promising, but it seems the GPS exif data is either not included or stripped.

```
{
        DPIHeight = 72;
        DPIWidth = 72;
        Orientation = 6;
        "{Exif}" =         {
          ... 
        };
        "{MakerApple}" =         {
          ...
        };
        "{TIFF}" =         {
          ...
        };
    };
```

I have searched through a ton of content talking about grabbing the url for the image and extracting the exif data, however I belive that this is only possible if the photo is picked from the gallery, not taken from the camera.

I also have CoreLocation turned on to 'Always', however that does not seem to make a difference.

If I take a photo from the photo app I know that the GPS exif data is included.  I can even add that photo from gallery into my app and it has the exif data.  However if I launch the camera from my app, seems I cannot get the GPS exif data.

Is this possible in iOS 11?